# Entity Update throws NPE for @ElementColection of Map

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have Department and Employee Entities. Employee table has three columns:

1. DEPARTMENT_ID
2. KEY
3. VALUE

Inserted the null value in my insert for non null key in the Employee table. I received `NullPointerException` during my update with non null value for existing key during `prop.put(key, value)`:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:514) at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap.put(IndirectMap.java:543)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.MapContainerPolicy.addInto(MapContainerPolicy.java:131)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.MappedKeyMapContainerPolicy.addInto(MappedKeyMapContainerPolicy.java:196)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeNonCursor(DataReadQuery.java:226)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataReadQuery.java:152)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:137)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:129)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.QueryBasedValueHolder.instantiate(QueryBasedValueHolder.java:116)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiateImpl(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:173)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.UnitOfWorkValueHolder.instantiate(UnitOfWorkValueHolder.java:234)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.DatabaseValueHolder.getValue(DatabaseValueHolder.java:89)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap.buildDelegate(IndirectMap.java:109)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap.getDelegate(IndirectMap.java:329)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectMap.put(IndirectMap.java:543)

EclipseLink version is 2.5.2

I have Department and Employee Entities and Department Entity class has the following relationship with Employee Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT" uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames  = { "NAME" }) })
@NamedQueries( {
  @NamedQuery(name = Department.findAll", query = "select d from Department  d"),
 @NamedQuery(name = Department.findByName", query = "select d from Department  d WHERE d.name = :name")})

public class Department implements Serializable { 

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn( name = "KEY")
    @Column( name = "VALUE")
    @CollectionTable(name="DEPARTMENT_PROP", joinColumns =     @joinColumn(name= "DEPARTMENT_ID))
    private final Map<String, String> props = new HashMap();


   public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
      return properties;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

No methods or persistent instance variables of the entity class may be
`final`. Removed this modifier from `props`, the mapping annotations look fine.

Be aware that in java version 7 you can't put null values because `java.util.Hashtable` doesn't allow it, and as you can see in the exception log it is the  implementation of map that EclipseLink uses. See [this java oficial doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

Comment: I removed final and still getting same issue.

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: Suggest you update your answer regarding HashMap ... you're referring to Hashtable (HashMap allows nulls). Where the Hashtable in the trace comes from ... maybe EclipseLink internal variable. Also methods can be final if persisting fields